# parsing PDB header information with python (protein structure files)?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

Is there a parser for PDB-files (Protein Data Bank) that can extract (most) information from the header/REMARK-section, like refinement statistics, etc.?

It might be worthwhile to note that I am mainly interested in accessing data from files right after they have been produced, not from structures that have already been deposited in the Protein Data Bank. This means that there is quite a variety of different "propriety" formats to deal with, depending on the refinement software used.

I've had a look at Biopython, but they explicitly state in the FAQ that "If you are interested in data mining the PDB header, you might want to look elsewhere because there is only limited support for this."

I am well aware that it would be a lot easier to extract this information from mmCIF-files, but unfortunately these are still not output routinely from many macromolecular crystallography programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I have found so far is converting the PDB-file into mmcif-format using pdb_extract (http://pdb-extract.wwpdb.org/ , either online or as a standalone).

The mmcif-file can be parsed using Biopythons Bio.PDB-module.
Writing to the mmcif-file is a bit trickier, Python PDBx seems to work reasonably well.

This, and other useful PDB-/mmcif-tools can be found at http://mmcif.wwpdb.org/docs/software-resources.html

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should try that library?
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bioservices